# Android - Disable TextView onClick in XML?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a list of various TextViews. Then I have an `onItemClick` handler to handle when the user clicks on the items.

Some of the TextViews I want to be clickable. Some I do not want to be clickable.

For the non-clickable TextViews I have them using the following XML

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_separator_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_none"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:enabled="false"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />
```

I have `enabled="false"` in there, but the item is still clickable. Is there an XML attribute I can use to make the TextView not clickable?

Or is the problem that I'm not really clicking the TextView but rather clicking the View that contains the TextView?

Is the only way to disable clicking is to do it programatically?

```
public void onItemClick(...)
{
  if ( // view is disabled )
    return;

  // else, do something
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure

```
android:clickable="false"
```

In code you could use the setClickable() method.

"Clickability" is something all View types and ViewGroups have, though you have to be a bit careful sometimes with how/when a ViewGroup passes a click (or not) to it's children.

Also, after checking, enabled does not appear to be a valid attribute for TextViews.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reasons it's not working for the TextView's in my app. It's kind of a complicated layout though. I'll just go with the programmatic way of doing it. Thanks anyways. I will mark your answer as accepted anyways because it probably works in most situations with normal layouts.

Comment: "Also, after checking, enabled does not appear to be a valid attribute for TextViews." What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score -2):

This works fine for me :

editText.setInputType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE);

Comment: Yes, but it is not an "in XML" solution.